# Performance issue after approx. 24h running time (Vaadin, Springboot)

Tags: spring-boot, performance, vaadin

My application is splitted into microservices and a frontend-app (springboot, Vaadin 21).
All parts performing well, but after round about 24h the ui becomes sluggish.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to tackle this problem?

Currently I just restart the service via cronjob - but that's not cool.

Best regards

Comment: FInd out what part becomes sluggish (is it the vaadin servlet, the backing services, ...). Add monitoring for the machines (especially monitor IO, load, JVM).  Add metrics like request times and structured logging to investigate. You will be incredibly lucky if someone can "remote diagnose" your problem with basically not much information given...

Comment: `SonarLint` or other code checkers should definitely be used.

Comment: I will check all the suggestions. I have never had such a problem.